# Topology on function spaces for pointwise convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces

Suppose I have some collection of maps $T_\lambda: C^\infty(\Omega)\rightarrow C^\infty(\Omega)$ which are linear and parameterized by a parameter $\lambda >0$. (Perhaps more generally take $C^\infty(\Omega)$ as a Hilbert Space or Banach Space of functions.)

If we have the property that for every $x\in \Omega$ and every $f \in C^\infty(\Omega)$, then 
$$
\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 0} T_\lambda f(x) = Tf(x).
$$

Can I express this in terms of a well-known operator norm on $C^\infty(\Omega)?$ If so, what is the strongest topology in which this is the case?

Comment: You can endow $C^\infty(\Omega)$ with the (very weak) locally convex topology of pointwise convergence having the seminorms $p_E(f) \max\{|f(x)|: x\in E\}$ with finite subsets $E$ of $\Omega$ and the space of continuous linear operators $L(C^\infty(\Omega))$ with the locally convex topology of "simple convergence" having the seminorms $q_{F,E}(T)= \max\{p_E(T(f)): f\in F\}$ with finite subsets $E$ of $\Omega$ and $F$ of $C^\infty(\Omega)$. I don't think that this is very useful.